# Tikzpicture inside forest node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, forest

I would like to embed a `tikzpicture` in a `forest` node label:

```
\documentclass[
    ,crop=true
    ,varwidth=\maxdimen
    ]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\Forest{
    [A\tikz{\node[circle,draw,inner sep=.15ex]{1};} [B] [C]]
}

\end{document}
```

However, the `\tikz` part is simply ignored:

[image]

Instead the root node label should look like this:

[image]

I bet it's very easy to accomplish, but I just don't get it.

Comment: your MWE produces the desired result with my installation, maybe an upgrade will help.

Comment: @Marijn: Yes, you're right! But rather a downgrade is necessary. It compiles as desired with old `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)`. The wrong output is generated with the more recent `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Cygwin)` and `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)`. Not nice.

Comment: I doubt that the version of `pdftex` is the problem, it is more likely a problem with `forest` (or possibly `tikz`).

Comment: Incidentally, I see the same behaviour with TL 2015. Would adding `\usepackage{pifont}` and using `A\ding{172}` be an option?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thanks for the workaround. Unfortunately, I need this for arbitrary numbers. So I switched back to a tikz-free solution: `\newcommand{\circled}[1]{\textcircled{\raisebox{-0.8pt}{#1}}}`. Still it's irritating that the recent TL 2015 seems to be broken here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nesting `tikzpicture` environments should be avoided. It guarantees unpredictability ;).

However, there is a straightforward way to do this using **forest** which provides a `tikz` key for adding annotations to nodes after the tree is drawn:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\Forest{
  [A, tikz={\node[circle, draw, inner sep=.15ex, right=0pt of .east]  {1};} [B] [C]]
}

\end{document}
```

[image: annotated root]

The advantage of this is that you can use relative node names. Here `.east` is the `east` anchor of the current node. We need to adjust the spacing to avoid having the nodes overlap. I've used `positioning` which is recommended, though you could do without it if you had to for some reason.

If you need the nodes closer, consider reducing or eliminating the `inner sep`:

```
\Forest{
  [A, tikz={\node[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, right=0pt of .east]  {1};} [B] [C]]
}
```

[image: adjusted separation]

or using a negative value:

```
\Forest{
  [A, tikz={\node[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, right=-2.5pt of .east]  {1};} [B] [C]]
}
```

[image: further adjusted]

## EDIT

The only problem with the above solution is that it is rather tedious if required frequently and the circled numbers may overlap with sibling nodes if the numbers get large.

Moreover, it is also possible - and perhaps slightly simpler - to use **forest**'s `label` option to create the circled number as a label for the node.

```
    label={[circle, draw, inner sep=.15ex, label distance=-2.5pt, anchor=west]east:<number to be circled>}
```

However, this is hardly less tedious to type. So, it would be convenient to create a style which allowed us to write, for example, `circ=89` to label the node with a circled `89`:

```
\forestset{
  circ/.style={
    label={[circle, draw, inner sep=.15ex, label distance=-2.5pt, anchor=west]east:#1}
  },
}
```

Now, we can write

```
\Forest
{
  [A, circ=3
    [B
      [D, circ=-4
    ]
  ]
    [C, circ=4499]
  ]
}
```

to produce

[image: circled numbers with style]

which is more convenient.

This works fine if the numbers are all on the border of the tree, but less well if they occur in between nodes within the tree:

[image: problematic overlap]

To solve this, we can increase the distance between the siblings for that particular node. We would like to do this automatically, but we only want to do it when necessary, so we add some conditional code to `circ`:

```
  circ/.style={
    label={[circle, draw, inner sep=.15ex, label distance=-2.5pt, anchor=west]east:#1},
    if level=0{}{
      if n'=1{}{
        if={equal(n_children("!u"),1)}{}{
            !u.s sep+/.pgfmath={width("#1")+.3ex+.8pt},
        }
      },
    },
  }
```

which produces this

[image: corrected positioning]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  circ/.style={
    label={[circle, draw, inner sep=.15ex, label distance=-2.5pt, anchor=west]east:#1},
    if level=0{}{
      if n'=1{}{
        if={equal(n_children("!u"),1)}{}{
            !u.s sep+/.pgfmath={width("#1")+.3ex+.8pt},
        }
      },
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}

\Forest
{
  [A, circ=3
    [B
      [D, circ=-4
        [E, circ=895]
        [F]
    ]
  ]
    [C, circ=4499]
  ]
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, very instructive! Is there a way to do this with `(3)` instead of `circle=3`?

Comment: @Timm You could, I guess, process the contents of the node so that you parsed for the occurrence of the parentheses and then split that part of the content out into the label. However, you would have to do that for every node, I think, so it would slow things down for large trees or lots of trees, and it would be a much less standard and, probably, a more fragile way of doing it. **Forest** really uses the `<key>=<value>` syntax and working with that is probably a better solution. Only I wouldn't use `circle` because that's a standard TikZ shape - hence my use of `circ`. Is it really an issue?

Comment: Sorry, I should have written `circ`. As for `(3)`, it's not really an issue. But it would look nicer: `[A,(3) [B] [C]]`.

Comment: I definitely don't think you could use `[A,(3)...` as you'd need to define a key like that. At most you could do `[A (3)` and then you have to process the content of the node. But I don't think it is a good idea for the reasons I gave above.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about the annotations!

Comment: How about the other way around? I would like to have a forest inside a tikz-node in a tikz-picture?

Comment: @towi Nesting tikzpicture environments should be avoided. It guarantees unpredictability ;). It doesn't matter whether you nest 1 inside 2 or 2 inside 1, nesting `tikzpicture`s should be avoided. You can use a save box, as in the answer below. Or you can do the tree first and build a picture around it.

Comment: This is already nearly what I need. But is there also a way to put the tikz content *inside* the label? Such as `some (1) text` in this example?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use saveboxes:

```
\documentclass[
    ,crop=true
    ,varwidth=\maxdimen
    ]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{A\tikz{\node[circle,draw,inner sep=.15ex]{1};}}

\Forest{
    [\usebox{\tempbox} [B] [C]]
}

\end{document}
```

[image: forrest]

Comment: So you need a box for every label you are going to use within the tree? I know you can reuse the boxes for another tree, but if you need, say, 20 such nodes in a single tree, you'll need 20 boxes, won't you?

Comment: @cfr - Yes, but inside a \bgroup .... \egroup you can use up to 256 boxes (32k with etex).

Comment: I was more thinking it would be a PITA to create them than that it would use up too many boxes ;).